# DecisionTreeClassifier Scikit-learn Print Logs

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Does anyone know how to enable logs for Scikit-Learn's DecisionTreeClassifier's .fit() method?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: please see updated post with code

Comment: `verbose` option is not present in `DecisionTreeClassifier`

Comment: yes that i already found in the documentation. I meant to ask if there's another way.